# How can i post JSON data to the facebook GRAPH API

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to post a message on my wall starting from json data?

So i can make a facebookPost class. Make a facebookPost object with the attributes i want. 
Serilize it to a json string and post this with the facebook graph feed method?

Or should i just use a dictionary and parse this into a querystring?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the step where you serialize it to a JSON string. A JSON object is just a collection of key:value pairs. The Graph API requires that you POST to a specific URL with your desired POST parameters (themselves key=value pairs) set. So yes, you can just create a query string instead of a JSON string and POST that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can post into a wall using Facebook Graph API..

Here are the things you have to read for detailed information..

[Grpah API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) && [Post method in graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: I know how to post. I've read these pages you've sent me. But there nothing about posting Json data. Anyway, thanks for your respons.